# Can't see textbox input with Foundation framework by Zurb (Firefox only)

Tags: firefox, textbox, zurb-foundation

I have a problem in viewing input that I write in a textbox. I am using Foundation Framework by Zurb http://foundation.zurb.com/

I have put a simple version up here http://mybookmarklet.herokuapp.com

(the bookmarklet part of the name is irrelevant to this question)

If you enter some text into the textbox then click "scrape" (using Firefox) you will see the problem - the input is alerted, as is supposed to happen. However it's not possible to actually view the text in the textbox.

Does anyone know if this is something that can be fixed?

PS. this isn't actually doing screen-scraping - the word scrape is not the best choice in hindsight.

PPS. Using Firefox 20, Mac OS 10.6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have applied too much padding on your textbox:

```
<input id="txt-scrape" type="text" style="padding:22px;" placeholder="http://">
```

You either make the height of the textbox larger to `62px` (that value will actually show the text) or make your padding smaller, `7px` is the maximum you can apply based on your styles.

Comment: Thanks very much, solves the problem ... and makes me feel pretty stupid ;)